# Split overflow text based on div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
</div class="demo"></div>
```

div height is `100px`. Div contains `text` paragraph. What i'm trying to do-

if text overflow occus, i mean paragraph height >100px
then split it into two part/data array

`part[1]` = text which will fit height 100px;

`part[2]` = rest part of the paragraph.

I.m confused what to use, JQuery or something else? how to split simple text content without any tag/class just based on div height? is it even possible to do?

Comment: What do you do with the `part[2]`?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava: I'll use part[2] text on another div.

Comment: What if part[1] is more than 100px?

Comment: Do you realize it is not that easy to know what overflows?

Comment: @EvikGhazarian: part[1] =text paragraph which will fit 100px, part[2]= rest content, which not needed to fit under 100px

Comment: @epascarello: You're right. So its not possible then?

Comment: It is possible, I am sure there is a dupe, You basically can add/remove text until the scrollbar appears.

Comment: @epascarello: Problem is, i need 02 data array based on overflow content. part-1 will use at one div, part 02 will use another div.

Comment: So you figure out what overflows and you stick it into an array...